# How to pass the following parameter? HitTestParameters3D in VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(,,,)?

Tags: wpf, hittest

I am trying to pass the HitTestParameters3D parameter to VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(,,,) but I've failed to find any examples as to how this can be done and information about HitTestParameters3D is scant.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks

Q

Answer (score 0):

Use [RayHitTestParameters class for the parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.hittestparameters3d.aspx).

```
RayHitTestParameters hitParams = 
        new RayHitTestParameters(
            new Point3D(0, 0, 0),
            new Vector3D(1, 0, 0)
            );
    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(visual3d, null, ResultCallback, hitParams);
```

Make sure to pass a Visual3D (for example, a ModelVisual3D) and [not your Viewport3D](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b6d35249-353a-4a14-a8a7-1b9dba9b6fca/how-to-do-hit-test-in-wpf-3d?forum=wpf) as that first parameter to HitTest. Otherwise, you'll get a "cannot convert from RayHitTestParameters to HitTestParameters" error.